How to avoid timeout in Wikidata - SPARQL for a specific query : SELECT DISTINCT all types values of a property?
I would like to get all DISTINCT type value of P31 property for all entities. For example :

Here the query:
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {  

  VALUES (?property) {
     (wdt:P31)
  }  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". }
  
}LIMIT 100

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%20%0A%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fproperty%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%28wdt%3AP31%29%0A%20%20%7D%20%20%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22fr%22.%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%7DOFFSET%200%20LIMIT%20100
Result is an exception timeout :
SPARQL-QUERY: queryStr=SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {  

  VALUES (?property) {
     (wdt:P31)
  }  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". }
  
}LIMIT 100
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.BigdataServlet.submitApiTask(BigdataServlet.java:292)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.QueryServlet.doSparqlQuery(QueryServlet.java:678)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.QueryServlet.doGet(QueryServlet.java:290)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.RESTServlet.doGet(RESTServlet.java:240)
    at com.bigdata.rdf.sail.webapp.MultiTenancyServlet.doGet(MultiTenancyServlet.java:273)


You are querying for values of schema:about, not for values of ?property (→ wdt:P31).

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to get. All subjects (aka Wikidata entities) with wdt:P31 or all objects (aka types)? Note, the former will be a huge result, see e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Statistics - there are currently 20,014,075,298 triples with 2,104,915,112 subjects (not all entities indeed, as also statements are subjects for lots of triples) in the data. Do you really want to get hundreds of millions of entities? I mean, the public service will for sure return a timeout as it is a shared service.

If you want all entities, then you should probably download the dump and process it locally somehow. If you want to get all distinct types, the your query has to be changed to ?article ?property ?item . There are 101,297 distinct types currently

@UninformedUser yes I wish all millions data for big data analysis purposes ;)

Ok, but do you mean the entities or the types of the entities, e.g. "person", "book", etc. ? The latter is indeed way smaller

All DISTINCT entities (Qxxxx) of all P31.
The changed query above ?article ?property ?item not working. it returns unexpected results. ie: Q1 for all languages. Could you provide a link to the sparql query please?
However,  The current 131GO dump is probably a good idea to improve my parsing perf. Thanks for the idea. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Database_download/fr

`SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {
VALUES (?property) {
(wdt:P31)
}
?article ?property ?item .
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". }
} LIMIT 100does indeed return all types of the entities. If you want all entities the query should beSELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription
WHERE {
?item wdt:P31 ?type.
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". }
} LIMIT 100- but that query will never work without theLIMIT`

The label SERVICE does hurt performance even for the LIMIT 100 query, so for that case using a subquery has to be used: SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {   {     SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 ?type. }     LIMIT 100   }   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". } }

Thank you. It is better but it is not distinct. I want the entity value of all entities with P31 is returned only once (unique or distinct). ^^

To try to clarify, I added a screenshot to the main question. For example in Q1490 Tokyo, I wish all checked value appears only once  in the results for all other entities P31 that may have similar Q values.
Maybe this is what you named .type ?

I don't get what you asking. Your original question was "get all DISTINCT value (entities) of P31 property for all entities" - P31 property assigns types to Wikidata entities - for example, New York or London have the type "city" and maybe also a type "capital". A person Brad Pitt might have the type "person". Based on my example, you can either get "all distinct entities" -> London, New York,  Brad Pitt or "all distinct types" -> city, person, book, ...

I don't get what you mean by the Tokyo screenshot We can consider Tokyo being a Wikidata entity - and there are tens or even hundreds of millions of those entities. Each of them has types via P31 property assigned. using SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 ?type. } gives all those entities, SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 ?type. } all distinct types. Your screenshots highlights some property statement with statement qualifiers - but those aren't even considered in your or my query

Sorry for confusion. So yes I was asking for types. I updated question.
With your explanation, I think I have the good query now :
SELECT ?type WHERE {   {     SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 ?type. }     OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1000   }   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". } }
just having the label of the type would be nice, if you know how to get it. Thanks

There are 101,334 distinct types. With this query SELECT (COUNT(distinct ?type) as ?count) WHERE {   {     SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 ?type. }     OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1000000000   }   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". } }
done :) Thanks again for your help.

to get the label: SELECT ?type ?typeLabel ... for the outer query

With the help of the others in question's comments, here the correct query :
    SELECT ?type ?typeLabel WHERE {
      {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE { ?item wdt:P31 ?type. }
        OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10000
      }
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "fr". }    
}

Use offset for pagignated results.
